# Replacing arrows of a complicated commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I have the following complicated pentagonal diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
\node(P0) at (90:2.6cm){$h(g(fe))$};
\node(P1) at (90+72:2.5cm){$h((gf)e)$} ;
\node(P2) at (90+2*72:2.5cm){\makebox[5ex][r]{$(h(gf))e$}};
\node(P3) at (90+3*72:2.5cm){\makebox[5ex][l]{$((hg)f)e$}};
\node(P4) at (90+4*72:2.5cm){$(hg)(fe)$};

\path[commutative diagrams/.cd,every arrow,every label]
(P0) edgenode [swap] {$\operatorname{id}_h,\alpha_{(e,f,g)}$} (P1)
(P1) edgenode [swap] {$\alpha_{(e,gf,h)}$} (P2)
(P2) edgenode [swap] {$\alpha_{(f,g,h)}, \operatorname{id}_e$} (P3)
(P4) edgenode {$\alpha_{(hg,f,e)}$} (P3)
(P0) edgenode {$\alpha_{(fe, g,h)}$} (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And now I want to replace each arrow $\rightarrow$ in this picture by a $\Rightarrow.$ What is the simplest method to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
every edge/.append style={/tikz/commutative diagrams/Rightarrow},
```

as in

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(P0) at (90:2.6cm){$h(g(fe))$};
\node(P1) at (90+72:2.5cm){$h((gf)e)$} ;
\node(P2) at (90+2*72:2.5cm){\makebox[5ex][r]{$(h(gf))e$}};
\node(P3) at (90+3*72:2.5cm){\makebox[5ex][l]{$((hg)f)e$}};
\node(P4) at (90+4*72:2.5cm){$(hg)(fe)$};

\path[every edge/.append style={/tikz/commutative diagrams/Rightarrow},
    commutative diagrams/.cd,every arrow,every label]
(P0) edgenode [swap] {$\operatorname{id}_h,\alpha_{(e,f,g)}$} (P1)
(P1) edgenode [swap] {$\alpha_{(e,gf,h)}$} (P2)
(P2) edgenode [swap] {$\alpha_{(f,g,h)}, \operatorname{id}_e$} (P3)
(P4) edgenode {$\alpha_{(hg,f,e)}$} (P3)
(P0) edgenode {$\alpha_{(fe, g,h)}$} (P4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for saving me!

Comment: @Bumblebee You're welcome! BTW, as the question is about the simplest way: `every edge/.append style={commutative diagrams/Rightarrow},` is simpler but IMHO perhaps a bit less clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tikzcd` directly. The input is even simpler.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
\node(P0) at (90:2.6cm){h(g(fe))};
\node(P1) at (90+72:2.5cm){h((gf)e)} ;
\node(P2) at (90+2*72:2.5cm){\makebox[5ex][r]{$(h(gf))e$}};
\node(P3) at (90+3*72:2.5cm){\makebox[5ex][l]{$((hg)f)e$}};
\node(P4) at (90+4*72:2.5cm){(hg)(fe)};

\arrow[from=P0,to=P1,"{\operatorname{id}_h,\alpha_{(e,f,g)}}"']
\arrow[from=P1,to=P2,"{\alpha_{(e,gf,h)}}"']
\arrow[from=P2,to=P3,"{\alpha_{(f,g,h)}, \operatorname{id}_e}"']
\arrow[from=P4,to=P3,"{\alpha_{(hg,f,e)}}"]
\arrow[from=P0,to=P4,"{\alpha_{(fe, g,h)}}"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't necessarily a good idea because you put stuff in a matrix, so you cannot wrap it in another matrix, which is possible with the OP's code, and so on. Also, what is the purpose of `column sep=large, row sep=large`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The OP wants a commutative diagram, not something to put in another matrix. About `column sep` and `row sep`, I'd ask you the same.

Comment: I just told you that this is not (necessarily) a good idea. We do not know what the OP wants, and if others see this they may wonder if it is a good idea to put all these `\node` commands in a `tikzcd` environment, which wraps its contents in a matrix. To the best of my knowledge it is not at all a good idea. To see this, just put some letter, e.g. an `a` somewhere in your code inside the `tikzcd` environment.